# Why doesn't the PHP Configuration Editor show up in WHM?

Tags: whm

I've seen countless tutorials and [official documentation](https://confluence2.cpanel.net/display/ALD/PHP+Configuration+Editor) pointing to the PHP Configuration Editor in WHM. However, there is no link to it in my WHM install at all.

**How can I enable it, and why isn't it showing up?**

[image: My Service Configuration page]

Comment: What version of WHM?  Current is 58.0.24

Comment: CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 standard – WHM 58.0 (build 24)

Comment: Did you solve this Leonard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a new WHM/CPANEL version with EasyApache4 you need to go: Software / MultiPHP INI editor.

Comment: If i click MultiPHP INI editor the page blank, can't able to change values.....

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are looking in the right place?  Your screen shot is of the Service Configuration section but for me PHP managers are under Software

[image: WHM Software section]

Have you tried typing `PHP` in the search box at the top left?

If it isn't there, since we both are on the same version of WHM it must be a setting by your host.  I wonder if you are on a virtual machine, if that has something to do with it.

First stop would be your host.  If they can't help you, lodge a ticket with cpanel, they are always really helpful

FWIW I am using easyapache4